# Prevent Duplicate entries in the same month access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that is updated every month but over about a week. TABLE1 has 4 important Fields `Date`, `Place`, `Location`, and `Reading`. In an effort to prevent duplicate table entries I have set the `Date`, `Place`, `Location` fields as Primary keys so that it wont let user enter duplicate Place, Location, Date combinations. This only works though if all three are a duplicate, if the date is a day later it is added to the table. Since my date entries can span several days this creates the potential for duplicate entries within the same month if the data entry is not done carefully or duplicate data is sent to the office a day later with the next batch of Place, locations, Readings.

Is there a way to make it so that no duplicate Place, Location combinations can be entered in the same month?
Place, Location, and Date all need to allow duplicates but not allow for all three to duplicate.

Comment: You can't create an index on part of an attribute (Month of your date) with Access. I assume that you have a GUI: that would be the place to perform your validation logic. Using VBA you can decompose your date into month,day,year, and enforce your business rules.

Comment: I am using a form to enter the data into the table, I am a huge novice when it comes to VBA. I had tried using calculated fields to separate the date into month and year fields but you cannot make a calculated field a Primary Key, which as I looked around is generally considered a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need one record for each month...

From the database perspective it is ok that Database accepts day later, since no duplicate combination detected...

First, as @nicomp said...
You can enforce your business logic using forms...

Second, you can alter your table and change combinations.. For example:

Divide "Date" attribute into 2 combinations, Month and Year... 
You will end up with 4 primary key combinations `Month (Integer)` `Year (Integer)` `Place` `Location`

Comment: I tried separating the Date field with calculated fields pulling just the Month and Year out of the date but calculated fields cannot be primary keys and after some research that looks like everyone agrees that is a bad thing to try to do. I am a novice when it comes to VBA. What is a better way to divide the date field without increasing the number of fields on the Form that need to be entered, if that is possible?

Comment: So in that case you have to validate Date before saving... I think proper way to do this... is to fix Day Value of Date... for example, in form you have selected 10.Dec.2015... and before saving record into table, you need to set Day to 1.. so you will end up with Date 01.Dec.2015 and Save it...

So the next time when user enters any date from December month and tries to save it, database will notify that duplicate key detected...

Answer (score 0):

Use a query as your source for the form:

```
Select 
    [Date], Place, Location, Reading, Format([Date], "yyyymm") As YearMonth
From
    YourTable
```

Now, in your form for data entry pull in `YearMonth` and, in the BeforeUpdate event, use something like:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[Place] = '" & Me!Place.Value & "' And Location = '" & Me!Location.Value & "' And YearMonth = " & Format(Me!Date.Value, "yyyymm") & ""
Cancel = Not rs.NoMatch

If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "Data for this month has been recorded."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of the "combined index of all the fields that you want to be unique.

[image: refer the screenshot]